# Как добавить css в markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

Пытался добавить в MarkDown что-то вроде этого:

```
<style>
mark{
    color:red;
}
</style>

<mark>what is DataBase</mark>
```

Но стили не сработали. Работает ли css в MarkDown?

Comment: А где именно не работает? Поиск показывает, что пример взят отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/66407948/8324991 и там написано, что в VS Code не показывает в плагине. А вы где смотрите, где вам нужно, чтобы работало? Сильно зависит же от того, где смотреть, везде он как-то по-разному рендерится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
mark{
    background-color: red
}
</style>
<mark>what is DataBase</mark>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]